# interact with cassandra in django?

Tags: django, cassandra

I am trying to make django interact with the cassandra database. I was going through the forums and found [this](https://github.com/enki/tragedy)

Can [this](https://github.com/enki/tragedy) interact with cassandra in django? and are there any libraries that can interact with cassandra in django?

Comment: Define "interacting with cassandra in django". There are a few python libraries for *cassandra*, and since *django* is in python then: yes, you can interact with cassandra in django. Or maybe you are asking if you can use cassandra for the orm in django?

Comment: yes iam asking if we can use cassandra for the orm in django

Answer (score 2):

In order to use *cassandra* (or any other NoSql db) with *django* you need to have a [backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/) which can support it. Luckily for you though, you're not the first to come up with the idea/need.

Take a look at these resources:

- [Django NoSql Support](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NoSqlSupport)
- [django_cassandra_backend](https://github.com/vaterlaus/django_cassandra_backend)
- [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel)
- [nosql-to-people](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/299775877/nosql-to-people)
- [making django and nosql play nice](http://www.slideshare.net/kingkilr/making-django-and-nosql-play-nice)

I haven't tried any on my own so can't say if anything is stable enough or gives an answer out of the box, but it should send you in the right direction.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to use Cassandra with Django is [cqlengine](https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine). It provides beautiful, django-like ORM and is really easy to use. The project seems active, last commit is from few days ago.

You can use it as is or with simple custom django database wrapper [django-cassandra-engine](https://github.com/r4fek/django-cassandra-engine).

Comment: Is using ORM with Cassandra faster than using ORM for MySQL if there is no issue of scalability? I've got around 200,000 entries in four tables with ForeignKey relations. Also, the fact that I'm using 'relations' in my tables makes me wonder if Cassandra is appropriate for my project.

Answer (score 0):

The best Python client is https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa. You can easily use this from django; https://github.com/twissandra/twissandra is one example.